# Renderflex overflow error on Pixel 6 emulator but not on physical device

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, android-emulator

I am trying to create a SizedBox which contains 2 buttons in a Row. The code for this is as below:

```
          SizedBox(
             width: 200,
             child: Row(
               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
               children: <Widget>[
                 OutlinedButton(
                     style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                       padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                           left: 20, right: 20, top: 10, bottom: 10),
                       side: const BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.blue),
                       shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                           borderRadius:
                               BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25))),
                     ),
                     onPressed: (() {}),
                     child: const Text(
                       "Cancel",
                       style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.blue),
                     )),
                 ElevatedButton(
                     style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                       padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                           left: 20, right: 20, top: 10, bottom: 10),
                       backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                       shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                           borderRadius:
                               BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(22))),
                     ),
                     onPressed: (() {}),
                     child: const Text(
                       "Save",
                       style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white),
                     )
                  ),
               ],
             ),
           )
```

On my phone (S20 Ultra) it works as expected, as shown below:
[screenshot of working layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMSrK.jpg)

However, when I run it on a Pixel 6 emulator, this is what it looks like:
[screenshot of overflow layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9oNS.png)

I also get this error when running it on the emulator, which I don't get when I run the app on my phone:

```
======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 174 pixels on the right.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Row Row:file:///C:/Users/ayazb/pomodoro_app/lib/screens/homePage.dart:213:22
The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.horizontal.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.

Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a ListView.

The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#37e84 relayoutBoundary=up3 OVERFLOWING
...  parentData: <none> (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=200.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...  size: Size(200.0, 48.0)
...  direction: horizontal
...  mainAxisAlignment: spaceEvenly
...  mainAxisSize: max
...  crossAxisAlignment: center
...  textDirection: ltr
...  verticalDirection: down
```

For some reason, the text in the buttons have a huge gap between the letters, which is increasing the button sizes and causing an overflow. I'm not sure why the text in the buttons have this gap on the emulator but not on my phone.

Anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Can you try to run in another emulator or run with debug mode in your S20 phone. And share what you're getting.

Comment: @RohanJariwala 
I ran it on a Nexus 6 emulator and get the same issue.
The error is fixed if I increase the width of the SizedBox to 400, but it looks like this: 
[link](https://imgur.com/VnPwm6u) which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hardcoding the width, try using a `LayoutBuilder` (recommended approach, [link to the API docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html)) or `MediaQuery.of(context).size` to scale the widgets according to the device screen size.

This way, you’ll have consistent UI across different screen sizes.